# Arduino USB serial connection to Raspberry Pi (Rasbian) not initializing

Tags: arduino, raspbian, raspberry-pi4

I have an Arduino Nano 33 iot that outputs data via Serial at 38400 baud, connected via USB. Setup starts with Serial.Begin. The Raspberry Pi 4, running Raspian buster is set up to receive the data. It can see the correct port, /dev/ttyACM0, but nothing comes in.

I even installed the correct Arduino IDE and SAMD board package on the Raspberry Pi. It still does not find it until after the IDE uploads the replacement sketch and the CPU is reset. The IDE can grab the serial number and board type though. I can then exit out of the IDE and the Arduino is still pumping out serial to the Raspberry Pi.

The only other way to make it work is by pressing the reset button on the Arduino every time a reboot is done on the Raspberry Pi. Serial was tested on the Pi using screen.

Neither of these options are convenient. What am I missing?

```
 /*
Connects via I2C to a CMPS14, outputs NMEA0183 HDM sentences via Serial (38400 baud)
   By James Henderson, 2014, adapted to output NMEA sentences by Ian Van Schaick
*/
#include <Keyboard.h>
#include <Wire.h>

#define CMPS14_ADDRESS 0x60  // Address of CMPS14 shifted right one bit for arduino wire library
#define ANGLE_8  1           // Register to read 8bit angle from


unsigned char high_byte, low_byte, angle8;
signed char pitch, roll;
float angle16;
int fine;
float bearingH; // Holds whole degrees of bearing
float bearingL; // Holds decimal digits of bearing
int bearing;
char nbsp;
char mystring[25];
char mystring2[25];
char mystring3[25];
int software;
int cal;
unsigned int _last_status;

uint8_t checksum(char *s)
{
  uint8_t c = 0;

  while (*s)
    c ^= *s++;
  return c;
}

void CMPS14_eraseProfil()
{
  Wire.beginTransmission(CMPS14_ADDRESS);
  Wire.write(0x00);
  Wire.write(0xE0);
  _last_status = Wire.endTransmission();

  delay(20); //  20ms delay after each of the three bytes send
  Wire.beginTransmission(CMPS14_ADDRESS);
  Wire.write(0x00);
  Wire.write(0xE5);
  _last_status = Wire.endTransmission();

  delay(20); //  20ms delay after each of the three bytes send
  Wire.beginTransmission(CMPS14_ADDRESS);
  Wire.write(0x00);
  Wire.write(0xE2);
  _last_status = Wire.endTransmission();

  delay(20); //  20ms delay after each of the three bytes send
}

//Correct heading for known deviation
int DeviationCorrect(int Head)
{
   return 0;
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(38400);  // Start serial port
  Wire.begin();
  nbsp = 32;
  //  CMPS14_eraseProfil();
}

void loop() {
  Wire.beginTransmission(CMPS14_ADDRESS);  //starts communication with CMPS14
  Wire.write(ANGLE_8);                     //Sends the register we wish to start reading from
  Wire.endTransmission();

  // Request 5 bytes from the CMPS14
  // this will give us the 8 bit bearing,
  // both bytes of the 16 bit bearing, pitch and roll
  Wire.requestFrom(CMPS14_ADDRESS, 26);

  while (Wire.available() < 26);       // Wait for all bytes to come back
  //  software = Wire.read();
  //  Serial.print("Version: ");
  //  Serial.println(software);
  angle8 = Wire.read();               // Read back the 5 bytes
  high_byte = Wire.read();
  low_byte = Wire.read();
  pitch = Wire.read();
  roll = Wire.read();

  //  int i = 6;
  //  while (i <= 25) {
  //    Wire.read();
  //    i++;
  //  }
  //
  //  cal = Wire.read();
  //  Serial.print("Cal: ");
  //  Serial.println(cal);

  bearing = ((high_byte << 8) + low_byte) / 10;
  fine = ((high_byte << 8) + low_byte) % 10;
  byte data[128] = "$HCHDM,";
  data[8] = bearing;
  //  int deviation = 0;
  //DeviationCorrect(bearing);
  //  bearing = bearing;
  //+ deviation;

  //Print out NMEA 0183 string HDM
  snprintf(mystring, sizeof(mystring), "$HCHDM,%d.%d,M", bearing , fine);
  uint8_t crc = checksum(mystring + 1);
  Serial.print(mystring);
  Serial.print("*");
  if (crc < 16) Serial.print("0");
  Serial.println(crc, HEX);

    //Print out NMEA 0183 string XDR for Pitch
    snprintf(mystring2, sizeof(mystring2), "$HCXDR,A,%d,D,PITCH", pitch);
    uint8_t crc2 = checksum(mystring2 + 1);
    Serial.print(mystring2);
    Serial.print("*");
    if(crc2 < 16) Serial.print("0");
    Serial.println(crc2, HEX);
  
    //Print out NMEA 0183 string XDR for Roll/Heel
    snprintf(mystring3, sizeof(mystring3), "$HCXDR,A,%d,D,ROLL", roll);
    uint8_t crc3 = checksum(mystring3 + 1);
    Serial.print(mystring3);
    Serial.print("*");
    if(crc3 < 16) Serial.print("0");
    Serial.println(crc3, HEX);
  delay(100);
}
```

Comment: What anout posting the code and connrction diagram?

Comment: Updated with Code from Arduino, don't really know why that is necessary. Also, added the connection. Arduino is connected to Pi using USB, tried both USB 2.0 and USB 3.0 ports on Pi. No change.

Comment: Add some (non-blocking) blink code to the arduino sketch (i.e. using the builtin LED) so that you see that it's actually booting. Your description looks a bit like the Arduino is not booting correctly until it is reset.

Comment: I actually just tested that.At the end of setup, I added a blink for the built-in LED. On power on, or after uploading a new sketch, I can see the Arduino leaves setup because the built-in LED blinks. (I used the code from Blink example, moved up to the end of setup.)